# mysqli select distinct 2 column in one table and distinct one column from two table

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have 3 tables

**table user**

id db_fname db_lname

```
1    xxx    yyyy

2    zzz    zzzz
```

**tbl_supplier**

```
id db_companyname

1  xxxxxxxxx
```

**tbl_subcontractor**

```
id db_companyname

1   zzzzzzzzzz

2   zzzzzzzzzz
```

**The results should be**

```
xxx yyy
zzz zzz
zzzzzzz
xxxxxxx
```

fname and lname should together

```
<?php
  $q=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT db_fname as fname from tbl_user
   UNION 
  SELECT db_lname as lname from tbl_user
  UNION 
  SELECT db_CompanyName as scn from tbl_supplier 
  UNION 
  SELECT db_CompanyName as sucn from tbl_subcontractor

  ")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  echo'<select name="txt_transferredto" class="form-control inpu-md">';

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
     $fname=$row['fname'];
     //$lname=$row['lname'];
     $companyname=$row['scn'];
     $subcompanyname=$row['sucn'];
     $name=$fname.' '.$lname;
  if($fname!=""){
   echo"<option value='$fname'>";echo $fname;echo"</option>";}
else if($subcompanyname!=""){      
    echo"<option value='$subcompanyname'>";echo $subcompanyname;echo"</option>";}
else if($companyname!=""){      
    echo"<option value='$companyname'>";echo $companyname;echo"</option>";}
  }

  echo'</select>';
  ?>
```

The code above give the result but I can't print together
and I have this problem

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: db_CompanyName in C:\wamp\www\order\projectmanagment\addactivities.php on line 147 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0026298808{main}(  )..\addactivities.php:0    ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: db_CompanyName in C:\wamp\www\order\projectmanagment\addactivities.php on line 148 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0026298808{main}(  )..\addactivities.php:0    ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: lname in C:\wamp\www\order\projectmanagment\addactivities.php on line 149 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0026298808{main}(  )..\addactivities.php:0
```

Comment: `SELECT db_fname from tbl_user
       UNION 
      SELECT db_lname from tbl_user
      UNION 
      SELECT db_CompanyName from tbl_supplier 
      UNION 
      SELECT db_CompanyName from tbl_subcontractor` run manually in PHPMyadmin, if its work, than you need to use alias. JUST SUGGESTION

Comment: he give me the same result but i want first name and last name be together

Comment: You could probably use the [CONCAT_WS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) MySQL function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use concat for first table

```
 SELECT concat(db_fname,' ' , db_lname)  from tbl_user
 UNION 
 SELECT db_CompanyName from tbl_supplier 
 UNION 
 SELECT db_CompanyName from tbl_subcontractor
```

Comment: this solve my first problem but it still this problem      ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: scn in C:\wamp\www\order\projectmanagment\addactivities.php on line 144 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0767298512{main}(  )..\addactivities.php:0    ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: sucn in C:\wamp\www\order\projectmanagment\addactivities.php on line 145 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0767298512{main}(  )..\addactivities.php:0

Comment: he give me this error but also give the result as i want